# Convert row to column by passing row value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table such as

```
Order_Id    InventoryId ItemType    total
1       5       Orange      5000
1       4       Apple       3000
2       1       Mango       3400
2       5       Orange      1700
```

If i pass order id '1' i need record like

```
Orange  Apple
5000    3000
```

If i pass order id '2' i need record like

```
Mango   Orange
3400    1700
```

how can i achieve this can any one help for the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN ItemType = 'Orange' THEN total ELSE 0 END) Orange,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ItemType = 'Apple' THEN total ELSE 0 END) Apple
FROM    TableNAme
WHERE   Order_Id = ?
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f99ce/1)

Comment: But that is harcoded i want to pass only order id to my order table as show at start so all item related to that order should come in column with total amount as value for that column as result is with only one row.

Comment: here's a dynamic version http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c1f8d/5, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c1f8d/6

Answer (score 0):

You should simple select the columns that you need like:

```
select ItemType,total from test33  where Order_Id=2;
```

The result is then:

```
Mango,  3400
Orange, 1700
```